# Android datepicker example API17

Tags: android

Can anyone give me good example of Android `DatePicker`?

I was following this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

But the problem is that `The method showDialog(int) from the type Activity is deprecated`. 
Can anyone suggest what to use instead of `Dialog`...?

Comment: Use a `DialogFragment` instead.

Comment: Added in API level 8 This method was deprecated in API level 13. Use the new DialogFragment class with FragmentManager instead; this is also available on older platforms through the Android compatibility package

Answer (score 2):

The recommendation is to use `DialogFragment` and `FragmentManager`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for clarification
[Android date picker](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker)